# Select to Count "Null" and "Not Null"

Tags: sql-server-2008, select

The following select is working when the `CLOSE_DATE` field `IS NOT NULL`:

```
SELECT
    YEAR (CLOSE_DATE) AS TheYear,
    MONTH (CLOSE_DATE) AS TheMonth,
    COUNT (*) AS cnt
FROM
    Table1
WHERE
    Table1.DEPT = 'SUPPORT'
GROUP BY
    YEAR (CLOSE_DATE),
    MONTH (CLOSE_DATE)
ORDER BY
    TheYear DESC,
    TheMonth DESC
```

The output is:

```
+-------------+------+
| Year | Month | cnt |
+-------------+------+
| 2014 |     4 |  10 |
| 2014 |     3 |   9 |
| 2014 |     2 |  15 |
| 2014 |     1 |  12 |
| 2013 |    12 |  10 |
| 2013 |    11 |  50 |
+--------------+-----+
```

If the `CLOSE_DATE` has, for example, 7 rows with `NULL`, the result will be:

```
+-------------+------+
| Year | Month | cnt |
+-------------+------+
| NULL |  NULL |   7 |
| 2014 |     4 |  10 |
| 2014 |     3 |   9 |
| 2014 |     2 |  15 |
| 2014 |     1 |  12 |
| 2013 |    12 |  10 |
| 2013 |    11 |  50 |
+--------------+-----+
```

The `NULL` indicates it should count for the actual year and month, so the expected result should be:

```
+-------------+------+
| Year | Month | cnt |
+-------------+------+
| 2014 |     4 |  17 |
| 2014 |     3 |   9 |
| 2014 |     2 |  15 |
| 2014 |     1 |  12 |
| 2013 |    12 |  10 |
| 2013 |    11 |  50 |
+--------------+-----+
```

**UPDATE**

The example above is just part of a bigger select. I Actually count for opened and closed cases.

If the ticket did not have a close_date it means it is open. So, intead of count as close it should count as open.

The select is the same, with open column:

```
SELECT
    YEAR (OPEN_DATE) AS TheYear,
    MONTH (OPEN_DATE) AS TheMonth,
    COUNT (*) AS cnt
FROM
    Table1
WHERE
    Table1.DEPT = 'SUPPORT'
GROUP BY
    YEAR (OPEN_DATE),
    MONTH (OPEN_DATE)
ORDER BY
    TheYear DESC,
    TheMonth DESC
```

So the line `YEAR (OPEN_DATE) AS TheYear,` and `MONTH (OPEN_DATE) AS TheMonth,` is bringing the year and month from the `open_date` column, but if the `close_date` column `is null` it should count on that line too.

This way all the rows with null values in the `close_date` will be treated as `open_date`.

Comment: Have you got your ans friend?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Isnull()` function, This function allows a another predefined value whenever `null` value occurs.

```
SELECT
    YEAR (Isnull(CLOSE_DATE,getdate())) AS TheYear,
    MONTH (Isnull(CLOSE_DATE,getdate())) AS TheMonth,
    COUNT (*) AS cnt
FROM
    Table1
WHERE
    Table1.DEPT = 'SUPPORT'
GROUP BY
    YEAR (Isnull(CLOSE_DATE,getdate())),
    MONTH (Isnull(CLOSE_DATE,getdate()))
ORDER BY
    TheYear DESC,
    TheMonth DESC
```

Comment: AK47, Thanks for your reply. But I made a mistake in the example and I just realized it now. I will update the post, hope you still could help.

Comment: Should be something like: `CASE WHEN (Isnull(YEAR(OPEN_DATE)) then Year(GETDATE()) else YEAR(OPEN_DATE) END as TheYear` ?